# stop setInterval while its running javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need to be able to stop a setInterval function while its running.
The idea is if the browser is resized then it will the timer (320px or less)
here is the interval:

```
var blurb_scroll = setInterval(function(){ 
        $(".content .blurb-container:first").next().css({'opacity':0}).delay(400).animate({'opacity':1}, 'fast');
        $(".content .blurb-container:first").animate({'margin-top':'-190px', 'opacity':'0'}, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).appendTo(blurb_container).removeAttr('style');
        });
    },6000);
```

Comment: `clearInterval( blurb_scroll )`

Comment: it doesnt work thats why I got frustrated and came here to ask.

Comment: @fogsy: Why didn't it work? What happened? Where did you call it?

Comment: What doesn't work? I see no attempt at using clearInterval().

Comment: And what do you mean by "it will the timer"? Is that event triggering the stop or the start of the timer?

Comment: Do you expect the animations to magically stop too?

Comment: Instead try SetTimeout(),clearTimeOut()..

Comment: @SLaks I called it at the end of the js so after the site loads if viewport is 400px or smaller : clearInterval(blurb_scroll)

Comment: @fogsy Is that what you want to happen? Stop the interval *and* the animations?

Comment: yes sir. thats what I want

Comment: @Ian .stop(); stopped the animation and resolved the issue thanks again

Comment: @fogsy Sounds good, I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

You must use clearInterval. Put the variable with your setInterval as global, then you can stop it anywhere.

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="clock">
<script language=javascript>
var int=self.setInterval(function(){clock()},1000);
function clock() {
  var d=new Date();
  var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("clock").value=t;
  }
</script>
</form>
<button onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)">Stop</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) you can find this example e much more info about clearInterval.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

To stop the interval as well as the animations, you need to use `clearInterval` (on the interval id) and `.stop()` (on the elements).

For example:

```
clearInterval(blurb_scroll);
$(".content .blurb-container:first").stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use clearInterval and jquery .stop() function according to jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Also as jquery states, animations may be stopped globally by setting the property $.fx.off to true. When this is done, all animation methods will immediately set elements to their final state when called, rather than displaying an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than clearing the setInterval interval, start using setTimeout instead:

```
(function runthis() {
  var f = $(".content .blurb-container:first")
  f.next()
   .css({'opacity':0})
   .delay(400)
   .animate({'opacity':1}, 'fast')
   .animate({'margin-top':'-190px', 'opacity':'0'}, 'slow', function(){
     $(this).appendTo(blurb_container).removeAttr('style');
   });
  if (conditional that says we should keep doing this) {
    setTimeout(runthis, 6000);
  }
}());
```

Now you have much finer control over what happens, and if your code has an error, at least it won't keep running your error code forever. If it dies on an error, you never schedule a new timeout.

setInterval. Just not a good idea.